# Update record function

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this code and I can't figure out why it's not working (the app just quits), I've been trying to fix it for hours now so if someone could give me a hand then that would be great..

```
public void updateBook(String Title, String Author)
{
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("KEY_AUTHOR", Author);
db.update(books, values, "Title="+ Title, null);
}
```

If I need to post any other parts of the code then let me know.

Comment: db=DatabaseClass.getWritableDatabase(), have you use this line...can you post some more code where you initialize the DB

Comment: errors log will explain you where is error ...

Answer (score 1):

change your update query as below:

```
db.update(books, values, "Title = ?", new String[]{Title});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
db.update(books, values, "Title = ?", new String[] {Title});
```

Comment: @becomputer06 Can the answer be updated to match. At first glance, the answer is wrong, until you read the comments. If there needs to be an update, please update it. (My own attempts to edit this were rejected...)

Comment: @becomputer06 I know, it was a mod. :-)